# Recently created index in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, indexing

How to find recently created index details in my SQL Server database? Any query to find this?

In my database there are a lot of indexes. I want to know which of those indexes were recently created, with all their details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SCHEMA changes history to know index creation changes along with many changes

Below is how you do it..

1.Right click server
2.Goto reports -->standard reports-->Schema changes history

below is screenshot from mt device

[image]

Default trace is enabled by default,unless you turn it on

below query tells you,if default trace status is ON

```
select * from sys.configurations where name like '%trace%'
```

below query can provide object creation stats

```
SELECT  OBJECT_NAME(objectid),objectname,indexid
FROM    sys.fn_trace_gettable(CONVERT(VARCHAR(150), ( SELECT TOP 1
                                                              f.[value]
                                                      FROM    sys.fn_trace_getinfo(NULL) f
                                                      WHERE   f.property = 2
                                                    )), DEFAULT) T
        JOIN sys.trace_events TE ON T.EventClass = TE.trace_event_id
        where DatabaseName=db_name()
ORDER BY t.StartTime ;
```

Comment: I tried this i got below message."currently this report does not have any data to show.because default trace does not contain relevant information"

Comment: Any query to find this?